# LSP server on_init per project configuration

Tags: lua, language-server-protocol, neovim

I'm noob in Lua and after many hours of searching, it wasn't successful.

I want to load some EFM language server configurations depends on a project setup. So, I found this: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/Project-local-settings

For example: in A project I have a "black" code formatter, in B project I have "yapf" code formatter.

After that I wrote custom on_init handler:

```lua
...
on_init = function(client)
  -- We need to register only available linters and formatters, because it improves perfomance↴
  local result = vim.fn.systemlist(
    [[ poetry run pip list --disable-pip-version-check | grep -w -o '^black \|^yapf \|^flake8 \|^isort \|^mypy ' ]]

  for _, package_name in pairs(result) do
    local package_config = M[string.gsub(package_name, "%s+", "")]
    if package_config then
      table.insert(client.config.settings.languages.python, package_config)
    end
  end

  client.notify("workspace/didChangeConfiguration")
  return true
end,
...
```

Well, it works, but i have a problem with a custom command, it's sync and freezes UI on first LSP load. Is it possible to load on_init async or execute cmd async?